# Result of subtracting indexes of an integer array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am currently studying C++ and I am confused with this code:

```
    int array[10];
    int* p1 = &array[3];
    int* p2 = &array[7];
    cout<<"p2-p1=" << p2 - p1 <<endl;
```

I thought the result would be 16 because one element of an integer array is 4-byte sized but the compiler says p2-p1=4. Is subtracting between pointers of an array ignores the size of bytes?

Comment: Correct: Pointer arithmetic uses the size of the underlying type.  It's much more useful to use pointer arithmetic to count the number of _elements_ in an array than it is to count bytes.  You can always cast your pointers to `const char*` if you want bytes.

Comment: All pointer arithmetic is done in "elements" rather than "bytes".

Comment: `int* p1 = &array[3]` is the same as `int* p1 = array + 3`. Maybe it becomes clearer this way.

Comment: ***type controls pointer arithmetic***. So `int *p;` where `p + 1` is the next `int` in memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't ignore the size of bytes, but the pointer knows the size of the pointed object. So 4 Bytes if it's an integer, 8 Bytes for double, ... . This works even for arrays of your own structs. I just added a picture for visualization of how this looks like.

[image: schematic array]

Comment: (nice picture...)

Comment: I don't know if this were sarcastic, but I just "painted" it with excel :D

Comment: No, actually I was being quite serious, A picture really is worth 1000 words.

Comment: ah yeah I know, when I learned C/C++ and all the pointer stuff, I always drawed what I just wrote to understand my code :D